# How to control reviewers in public repository

Tags: github

I have a public repository on github and 2 collaborators. I created a branch rule for code review. I want to review PRs only by myself, but there is an ability to set other collaborators as reviewes. Which setting do i need to allow to set as as review only me?

Comment: Since you say "collaborators", I assume this is a personal repository (as opposed to one in an organization). In a personal repository, you can't limit what collaborators can do, not even via temporary interaction limits; collaborators always have [these permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/permission-levels-for-a-personal-account-repository#collaborator-access-for-a-repository-owned-by-a-personal-account), which include PR reviews. Consider creating an organization for that repo.

Comment: Note that Git has no effect or control over GItHub permissions settings. Git does not "do" permissions, it leaves that to other systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you [protect your main branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-pull-request-reviews-before-merging) by [requiring pull request reviews before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#require-pull-request-reviews-before-merging), you can select "[`Require review from Code Owners`](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#creating-a-branch-protection-rule)".

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-20747/images/help/repository/PR-review-required-code-owner.png]

See "[About code owners](https://About%20code%20owners)": that would be where you can specify additional collaborator to be reviewers.